# Why should I not use collect() in my Python Transforms?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

**TL;DR:** I hear rumors that certain PySpark functions aren't advisable in Transforms, but I'm not sure what functions are wrong and why they are so?

Why can't I just `collect()` my data in certain circumstances to a list and iterate over the rows?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of pieces here one needs to understand to arrive at the final conclusion, namely that `collect()` and other functions are inefficient uses of Spark.

### Local vs. Distributed

First, let's cover the difference between local vs. distributed computation. In Spark, the `pyspark.sql.functions` and `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` operations you typically execute, such as `join()`, or `groupBy()` will delegate execution of these operations to the underlying Spark libraries for maximum possible performance. Think of this as using Python simply as a more convenient language on top of SQL where you are lazily describing the operations you want Spark to go do for you.

In this way, when you stick to SQL operations in PySpark, you can expect highly scalable performance, *but only for things you can express in SQL.* This is where people can typically take a lazy approach and implement their transformations using `for` loops instead of thinking about the best possible tactics.

Let's consider the case where you want to simply add a single value to an integer column in your DataFrame. You'll find on Stack Overflow and other places plenty of examples in some more subtle cases where they suggest using a `collect()` to bring the data into a Python list, looping over every row, and pushing the data back into a DataFrame when finished, which is one tactic you could do here. Let's think about what it means in practice, however: you are bringing your data which is hosted in Spark back to the driver of your build, for looping using a single thread in Python over each row, and adding a constant value to each row one at a time. If we instead found the (obvious in this case) SQL equivalent to this operation, Spark could take your data and in massively parallel add the value to individual rows. Namely, if you have 64 executors (instances of workers available to do the work of your job), then you'll have 64 'cores' (this isn't a perfect analogy but is close) to get the data split and sent to each for adding the value to the column. This will let you dramatically more quickly perform the end result operation you wanted.

Doing work on the driver is what I refer to as 'local' computation, and work in executors as 'parallel'.

This may be an obvious example here, but it often times is tough to remember this difference when dealing with more difficult transformations such as advanced windowing operations or linear algebra computations. Spark has libraries available to do matrix multiplications and manipulations in a distributed fashion, as well as some pretty advanced operations on Windows that require a bit more thinking about your problem first.

### Lazy evaluation

The most effective way to use PySpark is to dispatch your 'instructions' on how to build your DataFrame all at once, so that Spark can figure out the best way to materialize this data. In this way, functions that force the computation of a DataFrame so you can inspect it at some point in your code should be avoided if at all possible; they mean Spark is working extra to satisfy your `print()` statement or other method call instead of working towards writing out your data.

### Python in Java in Scala

The Python runtime is actually executing inside a JVM that is in turn talking to the Spark runtime, which is written in Scala. So, for every call to `collect()` where you wish to materialize your data in Python, Spark must materialize your data into a single, locally-available DataFrame, then synthesize this from Scala to its Java equivalent, then finally pass from the JVM to the Python equivalents before it is available to iterate over. This is an incredibly inefficient process that isn't possible to parallelize.
This results in operations that render your data to Python being *highly advisable to avoid*.

### Functions to avoid

So, what functions should you avoid?

- collect
- head
- take
- first
- show

Each of these methods will force execution on the DataFrame and bring the results back to the Python runtime for display / use. This means Spark won't have the opportunity to lazily figure out the most efficient way to compute upon your data and will instead be forced to bring back the data requested before proceeding with any other execution.